# Как в WebView загрузить картинку из памяти?

Tags: java, android

Создаю картинку вот так:

```
img1 = Bitmap.createBitmap(300, 300, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        canvasImg1 = new Canvas(img1);
```

Как указать при формировании HTML разметки, что картинку вывести не из Assets, а взять img1 (созданную программно) для использования?

Разметка HTML:

```
String txtHTML = "<html><body>" +
        "<img src=\"madagaskar.jpg\">"+
        "<p align=\"center\">Page HTML</p>"+
        "</body></html>";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте [вот так](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15717721/3212712) преобразовать картинку в строку и подставить её в `src` атрибут в html:

```
// Desired Bitmap and the html code, where you want to place it
Bitmap bitmap = YOUR_BITMAP;
String html="<html><body><img src='{IMAGE_PLACEHOLDER}' /></body></html>";

// Convert bitmap to Base64 encoded image for web
ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, byteArrayOutputStream);
byte[] byteArray = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
String imgageBase64 = Base64.encodeToString(byteArray, Base64.DEFAULT);
    String image = "data:image/png;base64," + imgageBase64;

// Use image for the img src parameter in your html and load to webview
html = html.replace("{IMAGE_PLACEHOLDER}", image);
```

Comment: Супер! Очень вам благодарен. А главное все просто и это дает потрясающие возможности формировать любую форму отчета в виде HTML.